Merge [html5-filesystem] and [origin-private-file-system]?
Despite what the cited one-off mailing list post said in 2014, it looks like the idea of an in-browser replica filesystem really did eventually take off, and is now adopted by all major browsers. (Firefox; Chrome)
Is there any reason not to merge these 2 tags?:

html5-filesystem
origin-private-file-system

With a few cursory Google queries, I can't find any evidence that what's now called OPFS is a distinct thing from the originally unpopular proposal the html5-filesystem refers to:

The File System API is an abandoned API intending to allow manipulating files and directories in a *virtualized* [sic] file system stored by the browser in a sandboxed area of the client system.
IMPORTANT: [sic] In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem API spec should be considered "clearly dead," as browsers have shown little interest in implementing it.


In spite of its name, the File System API cannot directly access the local file system. [sic] This is probably the most misunderstood aspect (and commonly asked question) about this API.
When writing data to the local system, web clients (browsers) do not locally store files according to their (virtual) file names [sic] as created in the script. Creating a file named "login.txt" in the API does not cause the client to store a real file called "login.txt" on the local file system.

If the tag is meant to refer — as the tag info currently states with maximal emphasis — to the original proposal for what is now called OPFS, then I suggest that they should be moved.
If the tag is not meant to refer to this, then I ask whether it should it be updated to remove all that verbiage?

I do not see a good reason to merge the two.
The File System API
html5-filesystem
The File System API allows a web page to manipulate files that the user has access to. This requires the user to grant explicit access. Once given, the page can read certain data from the disk like directory listing, file meta information, contents, etc. There are restrictions and checks in place to ensure privacy and security
Origin private file system (OPFS)
origin-private-file-system
OPFS is a subset of the File System API. OPFS provides a programmatic access to a file system hidden from the user. In a way, similar to local/session storage - the user needs not provide permission nor know that the webpage uses it.
However, OPFS is a distinct mechanism. Since the data is considered entirely separate from the user's:

there is no permission needed
there are less checks involved

this means operations are faster


there are different limits involved, like maximum size of the private data

OPFS is part of the File System API but not interchangeable with it. It seems OK to leave the two intact as questions might concern OPFS specifically or not.

Who came up with html5-filesystem tag though :/ It has absolutely nothing to do with html5.

@Gimby I actually had a sub-note that the tag probably should be renamed. But decided to remove it to keep the focus. The File System API is specified by WHATWG who are also responsible for the HTML5 standard. To be quite honest, I am not 100% sure whether on what the nomenclature would be here for the File System API.

I've edited my original post to make it clearer why I suggested that these tags should be moved. If we grant as you claim that [tag:html5-filesystem] is *supposed* to be used for the File System API broadly, then it needs to be edited to remove the bulk of the verbiage on its tag wiki and description loudly disclaiming that it's only to be used to refer to the originally unpopular proposal for what is now known as OPFS. The paragraph you posted under the tag, which describes the tag as referring to the broader API, is currently *nowhere* on the tag's page.

@JamesTheAwesomeDude you keep saying that, but the javascript filesystem API is still there and is pretty decently supported now.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API . The OFPS is a variation of it, not a replacement. VLAZ pretty clearly stated that in the answer.

@Gimby I understand that OPFS is generally one small part of the larger "File System API". But if you actually read the [tag:html5-filesystem] tag description as currently written, it disagrees with yours, mine, *and* VLAZ's understandings of what the "File System API" is, and it *explicitly* states that it only refers to the small subset now known as OPFS. (Check out the Question; I've edited it to include more context.)
